# Mock object in Android Unit test with kotlin - any() gives null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to test my classes and I need to mock a `static` class. My code is the following:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ToolTipUtil::class.java)
PowerMockito.`when`(ToolTipUtil.wasToolTipShown(any(Context::class.java), "")).thenReturn(true)
val context = mock(Context::class.java)
presenter.onResume(context)
verify(view).setMenuButtonShown(eq(false))
```

But in the second line it throws an error:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: any(Context::class.java) must not be null"
```

I've tried with [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and [befriending-kotlin-and-mockito](https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791) with no exit. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use static classes but actual instances you can mock or -even better- fake.

Answer (score 40):

Mockito often returns null when you call `any()` and that breaks kotlin's not null parameters.

In mockito-kotlin they have a separate function for it, called [anyOrNull()](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/1.x/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L47).

You can also create your own function, [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt#L38) they say that this should also work.

```
/**
 * Returns Mockito.any() as nullable type to avoid java.lang.IllegalStateException when
 * null is returned.
 */
fun <T> any(): T = Mockito.any<T>()
```

Comment: this works like a charm, but I don't get the magic jajajaja. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: There is a broken link: "[here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt#L38) they say that this should work". I can't edit  the post because there are too few differences.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code in your test class:

```
private fun <T> any(type : Class<T>): T {
    Mockito.any(type)
    return uninitialized()
}

private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

Comment: May need to add `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` before the `unitialized()` definition.

Answer (score -1):

When calling mock(), you don't have to pass in the class instance anymore. If the type can be inferred, you can just write:

```
val mock : MyClass = mock()
```

If the type cannot be inferred directly, use:

```
val mock = mock<MyClass>()
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: The problem is when doing any(Context::class.java), it returns null. Mocking an object is fine.